# textbox created in code behind do not read special characters asp.net

Tags: asp.net

We have a number of textbox created in code behind.

```
    TextBox[] txtCol = new TextBox[8];
    for (int j = 0; j <= 7; j++)
    {
       txtCol[j] = new TextBox();
    }
```

We need to allow the special characters or I mean to say html tags in textbox. I tried to use System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(txtCol1.Text) to allow special characters. After entering html tags and click on submit button ( which inserts record in database), nothing happens.
When debugging through IE below error message was displyed.

> 0x800a139e - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500

Suppose I remove html tags and place only content, record is inserted successfully to DB.
Could someone please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have added ValidateRequest="false" to page directive and using .NET 4.5

Comment: Yes, if you inspect the failed request, you'll likely find that the root problem is that ASP.NET's built-in security measures are blocking the input due to XSS filters. `ValidateRequest="false"` should resolve that. However, now your textbox is vulnerable to XSS (Cross-Site Scripting), since people could inject JavaScript into its value.

Comment: even after adding ValidateRequest="false" does not solve the issue

Comment: You need to dig into the failed request using either Developer Tools in your browser or perhaps Fiddler and find out what error message it's giving you. There's a chance that you've fixed one problem and uncovered another. Since it's ASP.NET AJAX, you'll probably have to look at the content of the request itself, and not your JavaScript console.

Comment: I am not convinced that is the problem. You need to study your network calls (i.e. stuff your browser requests) and determine the actual problem...

Comment: Thanks for replys. I added  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="4.5"/> in web.config file to fix the issue